# File.renameTo() no me renombra mi archivo en Java

Tags: java, archivo, java-jsonp

Quiero **renombrar** mi archivo "grafo.json" a "grafo.txt" (intente moverlo a un directorio distinto pero me dio error de que ya se estaba usando el archivo :C)

[image: Codigo y output en consola]

Codigo:

```
    System.out.println("Como quiero que quede:" + pJson.getPath().substring(0, pJson.getPath().length() - 4) + "txt");
    boolean success = pJson.renameTo(new File(pJson.getPath().substring(0, pJson.getPath().length() - 4) + "txt"));
    System.out.println("Success = " + success);
```

Deberian ser capaces de replicarlo si envian cualquier file .json a esta funcion, ignoren el nombre de la funcion porfavor.

Info de mi entorno

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
Java: 1.8.0_111; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.111-b14
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_111-b14
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)

Edit: Acabo de probarlo en otro computador igual win 10, netbeans 8.2 en un proyecto de prueba ubicado en "C:" y tampoco me renombra...

Voy a chequear mas a fondo la version de Java y ademas que en ambas uso dropbox, no se si eso pueda afectarme

Comment: Copie tu código en mi netbean tambien 8.2 y funciona correctamente. Se renombra bien a txt.  incluso con el archivo json abierto lo renombro sin problemas.

Comment: Comprueba que NO exista un archivo con el mismo nombre (ruta) al que quieres renombrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en que no cerre el FileReader que utilice en mi JSONParser, a continuacion muestro como **SI** da error y luego el fix que realice. Agradezco mucho toda la ayuda otorgada por todos <3

Codigo con el error:

```
Object jsonFile = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader(pFile));
JSONObject jsonRaw = (JSONObject) jsonFile;
JSONArray verticesJson = (JSONArray) jsonRaw.get("vertices");
```

Al crear una instancia de FileReader y hacer .close(), logre renombrar mi archivo e incluso moverlo de directorio, aqui el fix:

```
FileReader lector = new FileReader(pFile);
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
Object jsonFile = jParser.parse(lector);
lector.close();
//Hasta aqui el fix
JSONObject jsonRaw = (JSONObject) jsonFile;
JSONArray verticesJson = (JSONArray) jsonRaw.get("vertices");
```

Conclusion: Entiendan los ejemplos que toman de internet y siempre antes de modificar algun file, asegurense de que ese .close() se haya realizado en algun sitio.

Gracias a todos!

Comment: Deberías leer sobre try-with-resources para evitar errores por no añadir el close() en clases que implementan Closeable, como FileReader.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar usando el método move de la clase Files, que permite elegir qué hacer en caso de que el fichero destino exista.

```
Path origen = Paths.get("rutaAlFicheroOrigen");
Path destino = Paths.get("rutaAlFicheroDestino");

Files.move(origen, destino, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo! Esta respuesta me fue muy util para encontrar mi error, lo publicare como respuesta.